# Windows 8.1/10 Crashing on if-statements within while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, windows-10, windows-8.1, freeze

I have a simple block of code that works perfectly on Windows 7 machines and Ubuntu machines, but when I try to run it on 8.1/10 it freezes. I'm not sure why. I've tried 3.0/3.6/2.7 interpreters on variations of the code but it still freezes. Does anyone have a solution? The offending code is the if/else-statement at the bottom.

```
from graphics import *
def main():

  lowx = -10.0
  highx = +10.0
  lowy = -10.0
  highy = +10.0
  incx = 0.1

  points = []
  x = lowx
  while x <= highx:
      # y = EvaluatePostfix(postfix, x)
      if x > 0:
          y = x * x
      else:
          y = x * x * x
      points.append((x, y))
      x += incx

  # Graph
  win = GraphWin("My Graphing Calculator", 700, 700)
  win.setCoords(lowx, lowy, highx, highy)
  for i in range(len(points) - 1):
      p1 = Point(points[i][0], points[i][1])
      p2 = Point(points[i + 1][0], points[i + 1][1])
      line = Line(p1, p2)
      line.draw(win)

  while (True):
      user = input("type your answer")
      if user == "hello":
          print("there")
      else:
          print("bad")

  win.getMouse()  # Pause to view result
  win.close()  # Close window when done


main()
```

Comment: what's the output? does it prints `"type your answer"` ? or nothing? have you tried python 2 + raw_input instead?

Comment: How do you know it's the `if` statement if the script freezes?

Comment: I've removed it and it doesn't freeze.

Comment: It outputs "type your answer" -- but the graphics window goes unresponsive and the console freezes too. I've also re-written it in 2.7 and it still freezes.

Comment: I guess that graphics + console input doesn't mix well. Don't you have graphics prompt to replace it?

Comment: I'm more concerned about why it _only_ freezes in 8.1/10, but I could whip together a graphics prompt and try that.